# Google Web API can have own google resources?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I have a Java web server that it use's Google Calendar. I'm trying to develop a web app that has N calendars, where the web app can create own calendars where it can edit it and share it with app's users.

My doubt is if a Google Web API can have own google's resources (Calendars, Docs, Spread...) or only can handle user's resources.

If the answer is yes ¿How can create it? Follow the Google Calendars API and with a Google API Web App credentials, I try to get the list of calendars and create one, but the OAuth server response's with 401 unauthorized error.

I put a example of my code:

```
public class CalendarQuickstart {

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Apps Script";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

/**
 * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart. If modifying these
 * scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/ReservaSalaKeys.json";

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * 
 * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT
 *            The network HTTP Transport.
 * @return An authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 *             If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
 */
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = CalendarQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
            clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                    .setAccessType("offline").build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

    Iterator<CalendarListEntry> it = service.calendarList().list().execute().getItems().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next().getSummary());
    }

    int numberOfCalendars = service.calendarList().list().size();
    service.calendars().insert(
            new com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar().setSummary("Calendario " + numberOfCalendars + 1))
            .execute();
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your error have something to do with the credentials. The [401 error](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors) means that the access token you're using is either expired or invalid. Check the suggested actions mainly:

> - Get a new access token using the long-lived refresh token.
> - If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described    in [Authorizing requests with OAuth
>     2.0](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth).
> - If you are seeing this for a service account, check that you have    successfully completed all the steps in the [service account
>     page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Comment: That's responding to half of my questions. The service doesn't have permissions because doesn't receive an access token of Google service, that is because the app doesn't have a callback URL in an external domain.